# script python using nodetool for health check

Tags: python, cassandra, nodetool

I am looking for a  nodes health check python script  and I found the following script

```
from bottle import route, run
import glob
import json
import os
import subprocess
import time
import socket

 # This method is used to check the status of health of the node
 # on which this script is running. It makes used of nodetool and figures out the
 #  status of node.
@route('/check')
def getNodeStatus():
        list = []
        result = 1
        p = os.popen("nodetool status")
        while 1:
            line = p.readline()
            print "Line", line
            if not line =="":
                        ipData = line.split(" ")
                        if len(ipData) > 3:
                                localPort = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
                                if ipData[2] == localPort:
                                                if ipData[0] == "UN":
                                                        return  "cassandra is running"
            if not line: break
        return "cassandra is Not running"


# This method will tell overall health on the cluster by returning 0 for healthy cluster and 1
# as a response if more than onw third of nodes are unhealthy.
@route('/health')
def getclusterStatus():
        p = os.popen("nodetool status")
        count = 0
        healthynodes =0
        while 1:
            line = p.readline()
            if not line =="":
                        ipData = line.split(" ")
                        if len(ipData) > 3:
                                #Check for ipNodes
                                ipNode = ipData[2].split(".")
                                if len(ipNode) == 4:
                                        count = count +1
                                        localPort = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
                                        if ipData[0] == "UN":
                                               healthynodes = healthynodes + 1
            if not line: break
       # return "cassandra is Not running"
        health = healthynodes/count *100
        if(health > 66):
               return "cassandra is running"
        return "cassandra is Not running"

def main():
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it seems like if you have less than 2/3rds of the nodes running, that you will take ALL of them out of the load balancer. That seems wrong or not ?
any help please

Comment: what load balancer?

Comment: for example for OVH
The IP Load balancing is an IP address carried by the OVH network that distributes the load between the IP addresses of your various services in the data centers. It gives you better performance when faced with high traffic, fault tolerance and optimized response times, as close to users as possible with Anycast technology.

Comment: You shouldn't use load balancers in between your application and Cassandra, its an anti pattern. Let the driver and coordinator pick.

Comment: so what should I remove in the code then